# Co-ordinate of extremities of major axis

Tags: conic-sections

Ellipse has a focus (3,4), a directrix x+y−1=0 and an eccentricity of 1/2.

Using this information I find the equation of ellipse, but I can't find the co-ordinate of the extremities of major axis. Plz Help me.

Comment: Welcome to the website. You will find that simple "here is my question" posts that do not include any effort to solve the problem are generally ill-received. Would you mind sharing how you have tried to go about the solution, such as including the equation of the ellipse you found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line perpendicular to the directrix and passing through the focus, intersects the ellipse at the points you are looking for.